# in angularjs ng-switch child scope form is not available not be available on the parent scope

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

Access AT model object which written in `ng-switch` ,here `ng-switch` creates a child scope and the form is created on this scope. Hence the child scope form would not be available on the parent scope. 
Please do the help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

  <input type="radio" ng-model="fileType" value="Excel" style=" margin-left: 19px;" >Excel
  <input type="radio" ng-model="fileType" value="Text" style=" margin-left: 19px;" >Text

  <div ng-switch="fileType">
    <div ng-switch-default="Excel">
      <h4 style="margin-top: 15px;">
        <b>Analysis Type </b> 
        <input type="radio" ng-model="AT"  value="SRI"  style=" margin-left: 8px;" >SRI
        <input type="radio" ng-model="AT"   value="JAG" style=" margin-left: 23px;" >JAG
      </h4>
      <!-- {{AT}}  i am  able to acess it -->
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="Text">
      <h4 style="margin-top: 15px;"></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{fileType}} 
  {{AT}} <!-- how can i access it -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a scope inheritance problem due to [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) creating its own scope.

Use `ng-model="$parent.AT"` within `ng-switch` block

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

<input type="radio" ng-model="fileType"   value="Excel" style=" margin-left: 19px;" >Excel
<input type="radio" ng-model="fileType"   value="Text" style=" margin-left: 19px;" >Text

<div ng-switch="fileType">
          <div ng-switch-default="Excel">
    <h4 style="margin-top: 15px;"><b>Analysis Type </b> 
   <input type="radio" id="atype_sri" ng-model="$parent.AT"  value="SRI"  style=" margin-left: 8px;" ><label for="atype_sri">SRI</lable>
   <input type="radio" id="atype_jag" ng-model="$parent.AT"   value="JAG" style=" margin-left: 23px;" ><label for="atype_jag">JAG</label></h4>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="Text">
    <h4 style="margin-top: 15px;">         </h4>
            </div>
            </div>
 {{fileType}} 
     {{AT}} <!-- now you can access it -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for feed back